# Laravel - How to Approve all the posts of a particular Employee

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel-5.8, I have written a code for post of employees and it is working perfectly:

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $posts = Post::latest()->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->get();

    return view('admin.post.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

And it generates this view shown below. The view loads all the unapproved posts for a particular employee:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></th>
      <th>Is Approved</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($posts as $key=>$post)
     <tr>
       <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
       <td>{{ str_limit($post->title,'10') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $post->user->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $post->view_count }}</td>
       <td>
         @if($post->is_approved == true)
            <span class="badge bg-blue">Approved</span>
         @else
            <span class="badge bg-pink">Pending</span>
         @endif
       </td>
       <td>
          @if($post->status == true)
             <span class="badge bg-blue">Published</span>
          @else
             <span class="badge bg-pink">Pending</span>
          @endif
        </td>
       </tr>
         @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

```
<form action="{{route('admin.post.approve', $post->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> {{ trans('global.submit') }}</button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

I want to add a submit button to the view called approve. Once the button is clicked, it checks where is_approved is = 0 for the loaded employee and turns all the is_approved that relates to the employee (the loaded) data to 1.

I have written this function in the same controller, but I see that it will only work for a selected row:

```
public function approve($id){

    $post = Post::find($id);
    if ($post->is_approved == false){
        $post->is_approved = true;
        $post->save();
        $post->user->notify(new AuthorPostApprove($post));

        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Approved');
    }else{
        Toastr::info('Post is already Approved');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

and have this route/web.php

```
Route::get('posts/', 'PostController@index')->name('post.index');
Route::put('/post/{id}/approve', 'PostController@approve')->name('post.approve');
```

How do I re-write my Controller, view and route to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Just pass `employee_id` instead of `post_id` and change the logic in your modal as per requirement.

Comment: How? Can you just show me in the sample from the route, view and controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I do something like below

All you need to do is that *when user click the button then it should call for a function where that function will update all unapproved posts.* So Im implementing it as below.

First I load all the unapproved post of the current logged in user . With just adding extra where clause in to your index function

**Controoler for all unapproved posts**

```
  public function index()
    {  //Fetching all unapproved post and passing it into view

        $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
        $posts = Post::latest()->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('is_approved',0)->get();
        return view('admin.post.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

**Defining the route**

Define a route like below  first and that route will call for the function named as  approve_all_posts in PostController .

```
Route::post('/post/approve_all_posts', 'PostController@approve_all_posts')->name('post.approve.all');
```

**New function for update**

Then I make the function `approve_all_posts ()` in PostController

```
public function approve_all_posts(){

 $unapproved_post = Post::where('is_approved',0)->update(['is_approved' => 1]);
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Update blade file with button**

Then in `admin/post/index.blade.php`

I add a button called approve all posts like below

```
<a href ="{{ route('post.approve.all')}}" class="btn btn-success">Approve all unapproved posts</a>
```

Comment: Why did you use <a href ="{{ route('post.approve.all')}}" class="btn btn-success">Approve all unapproved posts</a> instead of submit button. I have this error "Page not found"

Comment: Hey you can use any of them there there is no need it to be a form or just a button WHICH CALLS THE FUNCTION DIRECTLY

Comment: If I use submit button, where do I put     route('post.approve.all')

Comment: Just for the action of the form

Comment: I think the reason is because there is no view blade for post.approve.all.  I'm confussed. What do I do to solve thisPage not found

Comment: No need of post.approve.all blade file. Are you on Anydesk?

Comment: Why did you add Request $request since I'm not dding any input

Comment: Yeah No need of Request

Comment: What do I put in place of request, How do you mean by "anydesk"

Comment: You can remove Request

Comment: OK. I've installed any desk.

Comment: Ive installed anydesk

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public function approve($id){

 $post = Post::where('employee_id', $id)
      ->where('is_approved', 0)
      ->update(['is_approved' => 1]);

if ($post){
    $post->user->notify(new AuthorPostApprove($post));
    Toastr::success('Post Successfully Approved');
} else {
    Toastr::info('Post is already Approved');
}

return redirect()->back();

}
```